# How can glycine act as a buffer at pH 6.00 and why?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

> How can glycine act as a buffer at pH 6.00 and why? Please use
> chemical equations to show how it can act as a buffer at this pH
> specifically?

My work:

At pH 6.00 glycine acts as a buffer, because at pH 6.00 the condition is acidic and glycine is an amino acid, so its zwitterion forms an equilibrium, which means there is a positive charge on the N of the amino group and a negative charge on the carboxylate. So there are no sudden pH changes and we know buffer solutions resist sudden pH changes, so at pH 6.00 glycine acts as a buffer solution.

Equation:

[image]

What I need explained:

HOW does glycine act as a buffer at pH 6.00 with chemical equations, meaning to show an example of how it specifically buffers another species at pH 6.00 with the proper chemical equations.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, as it just becomes a "homework-dump" (off topic) otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is not correct for pH 6; it should be for pH 1. For pH 6, the equation should be:
[image]

If an acid is added, then the equation becomes:
[image]

and if a base is added, then the equation is:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Glycine behaves as worst buffering agent along isoelectric point(pH = 6.1). Because In Zwitterion form, if there is a sudden addition of H+ ions then it behaves as a strong acidic compound because of NH3+ and COOH group. However, during an increase in pH, it behaves as Strong Basic Group due to COO- and NH2 radicals. Therefore it has its least buffering action around pH = 6.1 or pI point